# How to give validation in multi step form using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am working on a scenario where I have to do a multi-step form which I have already done, as well as the validation part. I am using `react-hook-form` for validation.

I have multi-step form:

- in the first form I have several fields and one radio button
- by default radio button is ticked on for `auto generated pass` so in this case I have nothing to do
- the second one is `let me create a password` so in this case one input field will be show and the user will create the password

**Issue**

In my final form I am doing the validation like below:

```
{
  fields: ["uname", "email", "password"], //to support multiple fields form
  component: (register, errors, defaultValues) => (
    <Form1
      register={register}
      errors={errors}
      defaultValues={defaultValues}
    />
  )
},
```

So to validate uname, email and password I am passing the values like above.

But when the radio button is ticked for auto generated password it is still  handling the validation, I click on next and it is not going to next for because of password field.

And if I check the radio button as `let me create the password` it goes to next form and when I came back by clicking `back` it is going to `auto generated password` again and it is not holding the previous state. For other input fields it is handling the previous values but not in case of radio button scenario.

[My full working code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-star-glgk9?file=/src/App.js:396-670)

Comment: have you seen this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeAkxVwsyMU

Comment: @Bill yes already, but there they have used routing, I am not using routing for this thing, I never should use that.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1** The reason is you `fields: ["uname", "email", "password"]` is fixed, `password` is always to be taken validation.
**Solution** Need to store state of `Form1` in App so you can check if the state of `auto generated password` is on remove password from the list

App.js

```
... other code
// need to move state and function form Form to app
const [show_input, setshow_input] = useState(false);

  const createInput = () => {
    setshow_input(true);
  };
  const auto_text = () => {
    setshow_input(false);
  };
  const forms = [
    {
      // validate based on show_input state
      fields: show_input ? ["uname", "email", "password"] : ["uname", "email"], //to support multiple fields form
      component: (register, errors, defaultValues) => (
        <Form1
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          defaultValues={defaultValues}
          auto_text={auto_text}
          createInput={createInput}
          show_input={show_input}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      fields: ["lname"],
      component: (register, errors, defaultValues) => (
        <Form2
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          defaultValues={defaultValues}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      component: (register, errors, defaultValues) => (
        <Form3
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          defaultValues={defaultValues}
        />
      )
    }
  ];
... other code
```

**Answer 2** When you go next the `Form1` is unmounted so its state is destroyed. When you store Form1's state in App.js you will fix this issue too

Bonus: It's prefered to use camalCase (E.g: showInput) rather than underscore (show_input)

[image: Edit serene-fast-jj8br]

Comment: Hey was using your code, and got stuck at one place I have put up a new question could you please check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241134/hot-validate-react-form

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you render the forms conditionally so all the previous form values are removed. The solution for this is to keep all forms mounted and just use `display: none` or `display: block` depending on which form is selected. This way all values will be persisted whenever you go to next or prev form or submit the form.

The second problem that you didn't remove the password field when it's unmounted so when `moveToNext` is called the `valid` argument in `triggerValidation` callback is always false. I fixed that by setting the fields for Form1 conditionally depending on if the password input is visible or not.

The third problem you are using `defaultValues` for the wrong purpose. You can get the current form values using `getValues()` which will return all the current values of the form.

I set the default value for `uname` field just as an example to show you how `defaultValues` should be used.

you can check the full solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-forest-75pzs?file=/src/App.js

here are all the changed files:

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form1 from "./components/Form1";
import Form2 from "./components/Form2";
import Form3 from "./components/Form3";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function MainComponent() {
  const {
    register,
    triggerValidation,
    defaultValues,
    errors,
    getValues
  } = useForm({
    // You can set default values here
    defaultValues: {
      uname: "Lol"
    }
  });
  console.log("Errors: ", errors);
  const [currentForm, setCurrentForm] = useState(0);

  // control password input visibility and Form1 fields
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);

  const showPassword = () => {
    setPasswordVisible(true);
  };
  const hidePassword = () => {
    setPasswordVisible(false);
  };

  const forms = [
    {
      fields: passwordVisible
        ? ["uname", "email", "password"]
        : ["uname", "email"],
      component: (register, errors) => (
        <Form1
          // a key is needed to render a list
          key={0}
          // this will be used to set the css display property to block or none on each form
          shouldDisplay={currentForm === 0}
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          showPassword={showPassword}
          hidePassword={hidePassword}
          passwordVisible={passwordVisible}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      fields: ["lname"],
      component: (register, errors) => (
        <Form2
          key={1}
          shouldDisplay={currentForm === 1}
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      component: (register, errors) => (
        <Form3
          key={2}
          shouldDisplay={currentForm === 2}
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          values={getValues()}
        />
      )
    }
  ];

  const moveToPrevious = () => {
    triggerValidation(forms[currentForm].fields).then(valid => {
      if (valid) setCurrentForm(currentForm - 1);
    });
  };

  const moveToNext = () => {
    triggerValidation(forms[currentForm].fields).then(valid => {
      if (valid) setCurrentForm(currentForm + 1);
    });
  };

  const prevButton = currentForm !== 0;
  const nextButton = currentForm !== forms.length - 1;
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log("whole form data - ", getValues());
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="progress">
        <div>{currentForm}</div>
      </div>

      {forms.map(form => form.component(register, errors))}

      {prevButton && (
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          type="button"
          onClick={moveToPrevious}
        >
          back
        </button>
      )}
      {nextButton && (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick={moveToNext}>
          next
        </button>
      )}

      {currentForm === 2 && (
        <button
          onClick={handleSubmit}
          className="btn btn-primary"
          type="submit"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainComponent;
```

Form1

```
import React from "react";

function Form1({
  register,
  errors,
  shouldDisplay,
  passwordVisible,
  showPassword,
  hidePassword
}) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: shouldDisplay ? "block" : "none" }}>
      <form autoComplete="on">
        <br />
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>User name</label>
          <input type="text" name="uname" ref={register({ required: true })} />
          {errors.uname && <span>required</span>}
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" ref={register({ required: true })} />
          {errors.email && <span>required</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <label className="form_label">Password</label>
            <div className="form-check">
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="auto_pass"
                  id="Radios1"
                  value="auto_pass"
                  className="form-check-input"
                  defaultChecked={true}
                  onChange={hidePassword}
                />
                Auto generated password
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check">
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="auto_pass"
                  id="Radios2"
                  value="let_me"
                  className="form-check-input"
                  onChange={showPassword}
                />
                Let me create the password
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          {passwordVisible && (
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mb-3">
              <label className="form_label">Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                className="form-control"
                ref={register({ required: true })}
              />
              {errors.password && (
                <span className="text-danger">Password is reguired</span>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form1;
```

Form2

```
import React from "react";

function Form2({ register, errors, shouldDisplay }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: shouldDisplay ? "block" : "none" }}>
      <form autoComplete="on">
        <br />
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>User last name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lname" ref={register({ required: true })} />
          {errors.lname && <span>required</span>}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form2;
```

Form3

```
import React from "react";

function Form3({ values, shouldDisplay }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: shouldDisplay ? "block" : "none" }}>
      <h3>Want to display all values here like below</h3>
      {Object.entries(values).map(([key, value]) => (
        <p key={key}>
          {key}: {value}
        </p>
      ))}

      <br />
      <p>So that use can check for any Wrong info</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form3;
```