# How to validate multistep form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a multi-step form, which I am making using react, to work on validation I am using `react-hook-form`.

I have already achieved 90% of things just one thing I am facing the issue is getting the second form data which is dynamic.

**What I am doing is**

- In my first form I have two fields when those are filled (validated) I am going to the next form
- In my next form I have two input fields and on the add button user can add multiple rows of fields as well and these are working fine

**issue**

- Now when I create new fields in the second form I want to validate them but not getting an idea how can I do that.

**What I have done**

In my main component, I am doing this for validation

```
const forms = [
  {
    fields: ['desig', 'dept'],
    component: () => (
      <Pro register={register} errors={errors} defaultValues={defaultValues} />
    ),
  },
  {
    fields: [
      `userInfo[0].fname`, // here I am facing issue if I am statically putting 0,1 then it is validating that perticular form
      `userInfo[0].sirname`,
    ],
    component: () => (
      <Basic
        register={register}
        errors={errors}
        defaultValues={defaultValues}
        inputHolder={inputHolder}
        deleteRow={deleteRow}
        addRow={addRow}
      />
    ),
  },
];
```

On click of submitting, I am doing this

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  triggerValidation(forms[currentForm].fields).then((valid) => {
    if (valid) {
      console.log('whole form data - ', JSON.stringify(defaultValues));
    }
  });
};
```

and here i want data as like below if two data is added in form2

```
    {
  "fname": "dsteve",
  "sname": "smith",
  "userInfo": [
    {
      "desig": "ddd",
      "dept": "deptee"
    },
    {
      "desig": "ddd",
      "dept": "deptee"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have done everything but here only I have been stuck, I know where the issue is

Instead of this

```
fields: ["fname", "sname"],
```

I have to do like this

```
fields:[`userInfo[0].name, `userInfo[0].sname],
```

This 0-1 I have to make dynamic as per indexes, I don't know what I am missing

I tried mapping the fields with index through `inputHolder`but it did not work

**Edit / Update**

If I am doing like this

```
fields:[`userInfo[0].name`,`userInfo[1].name`, `userInfo[0].sname`,`userInfo[1].sname],
```

So it is taking validation for two fields, but that is manually I am doming, if user creates more fields then that should take these fields dynamically.

Here is my code sandbox, which contains the full code

[Here is my code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-vaughan-y8tvr?file=/src/App.js)

**I am open to use any new approach but that should use `react-hook-form` and full fill what I am trying to do**

I don't know how to progrees with my approach now

Comment: You should add the whole component like this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64183942/9449426) so others people can help you more quickly.

Comment: @NearHuscarl hey in above link you are not doing validation, I think that is the main point whereI have been stuck.

Comment: My point is, there is not enough context for me to start debugging your code.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Hey I have edited my post by adding `code sandbox` link please do check

Comment: I'm just starting to play with this.  I think it will become more obvious what's going on if I break in into a few components instead of one.  But one potentially issue that I noticed already is that there's no way to remove a row once it's been added.

Comment: I'll come back to this later, but I did actually make some progress [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64241134-vk8y4?file=/src/components/Form3.js)

Comment: @LindaPaiste on click of back it is not going to previous form and also not getting the data the way I want on console, could you please check

Comment: @NearHuscarl hey could you please help me out, I am open to use any other approach if it full fills my requirement,I just want to make validations that data format I can make if I get data

Answer (score 4):

You can create an array of 2 empty strings where first one represents first row F name,and
second one represents first row S Name under yours inputHolder in the MainComponent:

```
 const [inputHolder, setinputHolder] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      fname: "",
      sname: ""
    }
  ]);
  const [names, setNames] = useState(["", ""]);
```

Next,every time the user ads a new row you add to empty strings in names array.

```
 const addRow = () => {
    console.log(inputHolder.length);
    let item = {
      id: inputHolder.length + 1,
      fname: "",
      sname: ""
    };
    setinputHolder([...inputHolder, item]);
    setNames([...names, "", ""]);
   
  };
```

Where each empty string represents F name and S name.
Finally,fields is set to names in second form:

```
fields: names,
      component: (register, errors, defaultValues) => (
        <Form2
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          defaultValues={defaultValues}
          inputHolder={inputHolder}
          addRow={addRow}
        />
```

Comment: Hey could you show me working code in `code sandbox` so that I can test

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use **yup** as a validation utils. It is a powerful tool.

1. Create two schemes for both of forms:

```
 import * as yup rom 'yup';
    
 const schema = yup.object().shape({
   field1: yup.string().required() // number, array - whatever,
   field2: yup.string().required(),
 })
```

Similar schema should be created for second form as well

2. Create first form and apply your validators by resolver

```
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';

const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
  resolver: yupResolver(schema),
});
```

3. Do the same for your second form - **useForm** + validation **resolver**.
4. next part is to make your second form being dynamic, so do use hook **useFieldArray**

```
const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
  name: 'userInfo', *// key, a part of path to access your fields - userInfo[n].fname*
  control: form.control, *// to connect you fields to basic form* 
});
```

5. Now you can create actions*(buttons/links)* and pass them **{append, remove}** actions.
6. **{fields}** should be rendered by .map as default. once you will try to validate your second form with **(n)** count off section - your schema would be applied to each of sections.

**there is another solution, you can skip part with second form(I would prefer this way if your second schema could be massive).**

you can connect your **useFieldArray** fields to first form, and your single validation schema looks like:

```
 import * as yup rom 'yup';
    
 const infoSchema = yup.object().schema({
   firstName: yup.string(),
   lastName: yup.string(),
 })

 *// enhance infoSchema to your expected logic.* 

 const schema = yup.object().shape({
   field1: yup.string().required() // number, array - whatever,
   field2: yup.string().required(),
   userInfo: yup.array().of(infoSchema),
 })
```